# Cómo agrupar varios valores de un enum en Java usando OR |

Tags: java, android

Tengo un enum definido `enum scope {CHAR,WORD,LINE,TEXT}` ¿Me pregunto si se puede concatenar más de una opción con OR `|`hacia una variable?

Es decir

```
scope myScope = WORD | LINE
```

Y cómo se detecteria si myScope uno de ellos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres hacer es guardar dos scopes en el mismo lugar, puedes utilizar un arreglo:

```
    Scope [] dosScopes = {Scope.WORD, Scope.LINE};
```

Lo puedes actualizar asi:

```
    dosScopes[0] = Scope.CHAR;
    dosScopes[1] = Scope.LINE;
```

Para detectar cual es el valor que esta en una variable de tipo Scope puedes utilizar un switch:

```
    switch (scopeVariable) {
        case WORD: System.out.println("El scope es WORD"); break;
        case CHAR: System.out.println("El scope es CHAR"); break;
        case LINE: System.out.println("El scope es LINE"); break;
        case TEXT: System.out.println("El scope es TEXT");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que en Java no se pueden concatenar **enums** a no ser que sea en métodos de String.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414755/can-enums-be-subclassed-to-add-new-elements

No pregunta exactamente lo que tu preguntas pero si que se acerca ,y puede ayudarte.

Aunque yo creo que es imposible lo de tu respuesta , pero que responda un experto sobre esto , que seguro que tienen más idea que yo